# When should I commit and push in Test Driven Development?

Tags: version-control, tdd, push, commit

My question regards TDD and when should I commit or push changes?

I'm wondering is it fine to push the code where some values returned by function are still faked or implementation is obvious to pass the test but interface exists.
In other words may I push the code before redactor? Or otherwise: may I push the code which does not change "interface" but does not do actually work yet?

I'm not telling about unit tests but more some integration/acceptance end-to-end tests where e.g. I'm getting some data from tool A, send it to tool B and check is database record was created. Implementing such tests is often time consuming and contains many asserts at the end but pushing early version of code allow another team member to work based on our part of work.

Thank you for answering this question in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's a single answer for this - it depends highly on your workflows and also on the version control system used.

Answer (score 6):

A development workflow is always some consensus between the developers that it involves, so there are no fixed rules in play here.  You need to coordinate with the other developers to figure out what works best for you.

That said, my personal approach here is that you should never break the remote master.  Instead, commit and push to a branch as soon as you have something that compiles (even if the tests fail), and then merge with master once your tests pass, i.e., only push *working* code to master, but have your non-working tests on a branch whenever you like.

If you have any kind of continuous integration system in place, this workflow ensures that you never end up breaking your CI build by pushing a bunch of failing tests to the branch that the CI system is going to pick up and test.

Comment: +1 assuming they are using git/hg

Comment: Hah. Yeah, if it turns out they aren't using git/hg then my answer is modified to "never commit anything it's going to go horribly wrong just abandon all hope now and email patches to one another".

Comment: We are using distributed version control where commit/push equivalents exist.

Comment: Excellent!  Then my advice stands.  Use branches everywhere and often, and you'll always have a working HEAD/master.

Comment: Thanks. However this is not fully answering my question. In your terms question is: whether HEAD may contains not fully re-factored code with tests passing thanks to partially faked or obvious implementation?

Comment: If you're doing real TDD and all your tests are passing then you are done and you should step away from the keyboard.  Or write more tests.  It seems perfectly safe to commit TDD code for which all tests are passing.  If that would result in functionality being broken or missing, then your tests are not sufficiently exhaustive and you have a different problem than your versioning workflow.

Comment: Please read my question more carefully. I'm trying to explain my self best I can. Not fully re-factored, partially faked or obvious implementations may be good enough for your team members to start working based on your solution. Even if it is not fully ready yet. Like I said I'm not taking about unit tests where situation is obvious but more complex end-to-end tests where being done takes more time but such situation may block your colleagues.

Comment: OK, so doesn't my answer still apply?  You can do whatever you like on a branch.  Just don't commit anything to HEAD that could be considered "broken", where "broken" is going to be defined entirely in terms of you and your team mates' objectives and development workflows, and the expectations around whether the product is usable in any given state. I'm afraid I can't be much more specific than "don't break the build".